# Regex string to detect hashtags without special characters

Tags: android, ios, regex

We want to dis-allow all special characters in a hash-tag, except underscores?

For example:

**My input string**

```java
Hello. #te$t #te_st #tes%12 #__test
```

The valid hashtags are:

```java
#te
#te_st
tes
__test
```

The special characters break the hashtags.

**My regex**:

```java
\B[#]\S+\b
```

which only splits by hashtags.

Could someone tell me how to create the expression for this specific match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
\B#\w+
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fAG3gv/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```